# In Excel / VBA: Change cell bg color using custom hex code from another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of hex codes in Column C. I want to change the background color of the cells in Column A so there's a visual example of the hex code's color on each line. Is there an easy way to automate this?

I used the Record Macro tool to copy the hex in C1 and paste it as the custom fill color in A1, but that recorded the value and not the act of pasting a value, if that makes sense. Rather than creating a macro that would copy and paste a given line's hex code, it created a macro that would always paste a specific hex code (say, #F89D5E) in every row.

I think I ought to be able to tell Excel to copy & paste, or simply to reference the hex code cells when coloring the visual example cells (so it updates itself without being triggered by a macro) - I just don't know how.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Probably, using a loop.

Comment: Range("A6").Interior.Color = *<hexvalue>*...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a macro like this:

```
Sub ReadColor()
   Dim c As String
   c = Range("C1").Value  ' #F89D5E
   Range("A1").Interior.Color = Replace(c, "#", "&H")
   Range("A2").Interior.Color = RGB(&H5E, &H9D, &HF8)
End Sub
```

In VBA hex numbers begin form `&H`. The RGB order is reversed.
[image: ReadHexColor]

Answer (score 0):

Excel understands the syntax for hex colours like this -

```
Sub sbHexCode()
 Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color = &HFF
 Cells(1, 2).Interior.Color = &HCC
 Cells(1, 3).Interior.Color = &H0
 Cells(1, 4).Interior.Color = &HFFFF00
 Cells(1, 5).Interior.Color = &H11FF00
 Cells(2, 1) = "&HFF"
 Cells(2, 2) = "&HCC"
 Cells(2, 3) = "&H0"
 Cells(2, 4) = "&HFFFF00"
 Cells(2, 5) = "&H11FF00"
 Cells(3, 1).Interior.Color = Cells(2, 1)
 Cells(3, 2).Interior.Color = Cells(2, 2)
 Cells(3, 3).Interior.Color = Cells(2, 3)
 Cells(3, 4).Interior.Color = Cells(2, 4)
 Cells(3, 5).Interior.Color = Cells(2, 5)
' https://htmlcolorcodes.com/colors/shades-of-green/
End Sub
```